# Nativescript - How to hide a menu bellow the bottom?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have these two images where one is on top of the other : (twitter image and black image):

[image]

The black image should be hidden  at bottom - and when a user clicks the twitter page - ***the black menu should slide-in from bottom***.

The black image is in the middle (on top of the other image) since the outside Gridview doesn't have any rows  - so everything is placed as a z-index stack:

```
<GridLayout   columns="*"  >
 <GridLayout slide-out>
        <Image src="~/images/page.png"    ></Image>
    </GridLayout>

    <StackLayout slide-in class="slide b" height="300" >
        <Image   src="~/images/replies.png" "></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

But the Black image ( which held by Stacklayout) should be hidden at the bottom like this :

[image: ------------------]

Is it possible to hide it at the bottom via css ?

**What have I tried so far ?**

As you see there is a directive on the Stacklayout (named `slide-in`) :

So I set its `marginBottom` on startup  :

```
 constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.element.nativeElement.marginBottom = 0;
    }
```

But the Stacklayout stays the same  ( in the middle)/

If I set

```
 this.element.nativeElement.marginBottom = -screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs;
```

It shows :

[image]

But it should be completly hidden at bottom

**Question:**

How can I hide it at the bottom ?

Comment: Did you try css display:none; ?

Comment: @Sentry I want to slide it in from bottom. Sorry for not mention that. I've edited the question and added that info. thank you.

Comment: You could also try to do negative margin like margin-bottom:-100px; and try to add position:absolute; to the img. maybe that will work

Comment: @Sentry the problem is that I don't know which value at : `margin-bottom:XXX; `. I don;t want to put it manually - i want to it be calculated automatically. How can I do that ?

Comment: Try margin-bottom:-100vh; or margin-top:100vh;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use translate on the y axis so translate-y=-400 also set the opacity to 0 and animate both of those properties with the animation API for the view component to animate in and out. My talk at dev days covered this and the example is on a repo of mine. On phone now or I'd link it.

Comment: I've changed it to your suggestion as the same value as height but look how it looks : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPSnH.png

Comment: Then translate the opposite direction and don't forget opacity. Make it a really high value to throw it far off the axis so it's completely hidden then tweak your animation duration. Just takes some trial and error :) you're almost there.

Comment: First of all thank you. I just wanted NOT to take a high value but the EXACT value of screen height. And now you're telling me  " a high value". So I'll listen to you. ( i'd love to hear the reason). Thanks again.